Qiskit - Parallelization of a quantum circuit
I have the following circuit, which is the implementation of a quantum oracle for a fuzzy inference engine: 
As you can see this is composed of blocks, between barriers, which can be considered independent. Since the depth of the transpiled circuit is prohibitive (more than 1000), I am trying to reduce it at the expense of the width by executing the blocks in parallel, I mean leveraging the available 127 qubits available on IBM real backend.
Do you know if there's a way in Qiskit to automatically do it?
EDIT:
I managed to decompose my circuit in subcircuits and assemble them in parallel as in the following image. For doing that I defined a new quantum circuit and used the function quantum_circuit.append(subcircuit) specifying the correct qubits to use for each subcircuit.
Sadly I found out that the result from this new circuit is even worse than the one from the original one. Is it because of the width?


A simple and effective way to reduce the depth of this circuit is to use ancilla qubits.
First add ancilla register and add it to your circuit:
anc = QuantumRegister(2, 'anc')
circ = QuantumCircuit(theta, omega, anc, current, cr)

then, change the mode of every multi-controlled NOT gate to be 'v-chain' and pass the ancilla qubits. For example,
circ.mcx(theta[:] + omega[:], current[2], ancilla_qubits=anc, mode='v-chain')

When I transpiled the original circuit against FakeTorino I got
Depth: 1690, 2Q Depth: 558

and when I transpiled the circuit with ancillas I got
Depth: 882, 2Q Depth: 223


Note that: if the input state to omega register is actually the vector state
$\left[{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}}\right]$, you can replace the multi-controlled NOTs with Toffoli gates which will reduce the circuit depth dramatically.

Thank you @Egretta.Thula, actually I am already applying v-chain approach (although I put the image of the original circuit) but the circuit is yet too deep, that is why I want to split it in blocks.
